# PostgreSQL - Create table and set specific date format

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, date-format, create-table

I want to create a new table and set a date type with a specific format. Is that possible?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
... 
EXPIRATION DATE " YYYY/MM"
... 
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgresql date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467031/postgresql-date-format)

Comment: I think the "duplicated" answer gets to what you want. If this is not the case, ignore the comment above but I think that the linked question will do what you want.

Comment: Dates don't have a "format"

Comment: @DrColossos I just wondered if there is a way to set the date's format to a specific format, so that any other input would not be accepted. For example, to set the default format as "YYYY/MM" and if anyone tried to insert data with format "YYYY/MM/dd", he would not succeed.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest a different approach: *Never* store date / time as [character type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) (`text`, `varchar()`, ...) to begin with. Use an [appropriate type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html), probably `date` in your case.

Also, *never* use [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as identifier. `user` is just not possible to begin with, you would have to double-quote, which I would discourage.
Could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE usr (
  usr_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 ,usr text UNIQUE
 ,expiration_date date
  ... 
);
```

Now, various input formats are possible, as long as they are unambiguous. The [related question @DrColossos has linked to in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467031/postgresql-date-format) has more on that.
[The manual has all the details.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT)

To enforce a particular **input** format, you could run the text literal through the [`to_date()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) function. Example:

```
INSERT INTO usr (usr, expiration_date)
VALUES ('flippin_user', to_date($my_date_literal, ' YYYY/MM');
```

Note: if you include the *leading blank* in the pattern, it is expected from the input!

Finally, you can format your date any way you like with [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) on **output**:

```
SELECT usr, to_char(expiration_date, ' YYYY/MM') AS formatted_exp_date
WHERE  usr_id = 1;
```

Comment: You are right for the reversed words, I just used 'user' as an example. My point is that I want to insert data from excel files, so I use the command `COPY usr FROM 'C:\usr.csv' 
WITH (FORMAT CSV,HEADER);` . Can I use something similar to your advice in that command?

Comment: @D-Lef: This is a new question. [Consider this related answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130594/postgresql-how-to-convert-string-date-to-timestamp-without-knowing-the-date-form/8130748#8130748)

Comment: Thanks. As I mention in a comment above, I wondered if there is a way to "lock" the date format, when I create the table.

Comment: @D-Lef: Not with a `date` column, when users can INSERT INTO the table directly. Type conversion happens before any other checks. You would have to operate with a `text` column ... brrr.